# JavaScript functional programing with compose function and Array.reduce

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, setinterval

I am new to JavaScript Functional programming. In code below, `compose` can't work without `setInterval` outside it and `clear` as the first argument also does't give the `compose` initial value.

So my question is how can `compose` work without the `setInterval`?

```js
const clear = () => console.clear()
const f1 = () => 2
const log = message => console.log(message)

const compose = (...fns) =>
    arg =>
        fns.reduce(
            (composed, f) => f(composed),
            arg
        )

setInterval(
    compose(clear, f1, log), 1000
)
```

Comment: FYI, [tag:compose] has nothing to do with this. Please refer to the tag wiki in the future for usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`compose(...fns)` returns a function. When used with `setInterval`, it is being called implicitly by the JavaScript engine.

If you want to use it directly, you can do something like:

```js
const clear = () => console.clear()
const f1 = () => 2
const log = message => console.log(message)

const compose = (...fns) =>
    arg =>
        fns.reduce(
            (composed, f) => f(composed),
            arg
        )

compose(clear, f1, log)();
```